# Javascript addEventListener runs only once

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have been trying to build a very simple site that will pull up an informational card in response to a user's click on a building represented in the UI and get rid of the card when the user clicks on the compass img in the corner. The code applies two different CSS classes to get the card to appear and disappear. I was able to make the addEventListener work on both the building and the compass, but it only works once. In other words, after clicking on the building once, the card appears, then disappears after clicking on the compass. But, any further clicks after those first two do not seem to register. At least, the card doesn't appear and disappear anymore.

This seems simple, but I haven't been able to figure out why the buttons only work once.

I've been writing in SublimeText and viewing the site in my browser. Please let me know if you have any thoughts on why this is happening?!

```js
//stores marker as variable
var wsc = document.getElementById("wsc");
//stores event function
var onBuildingClick = function() {
 document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.add("card");
}
//adds event listener to marker
wsc.addEventListener("click", onBuildingClick);



//////////////////////////////////


//stores compass as a variable
var compass = document.getElementById("compass_img");
//stores event function
var onCompassClick = function() {
 document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.add("_card");
}
//adds event listener to compass
compass.addEventListener("click", onCompassClick);
```

```css
.card {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 width: 60%;
 height: 60%;
 left: 20%;
 top: 20%;
}
._card {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="byu_richmap.css">

<title>byu_richmap</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="campus_map">
  <img id="campus_img" src="BYUmap_simple.png">
  <div id="wsc" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="hbll" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="hfac" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="moa" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="asb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="jkb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="tmcb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="jfsb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="swkt" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="esc" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="kc" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="marb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="cb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="ctb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="lsb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="brwb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="snlb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="rotc" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="jrcb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="mlbm" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="mc" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="hc" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="tnrb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="bnsb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="hgb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="msrb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="brmb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="mckb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="rb" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="lves" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="canc" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="sab" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="sfh" class="identifier"></div>

  <div id="_wsc" class="cards"></div>
  <!--<div id="_hbll" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_hfac" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_moa" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_asb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_jkb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_tmcb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_jfsb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_swkt" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_esc" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_kc" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_marb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_cb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_ctb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_lsb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_brwb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_snlb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_rotc" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_jrcb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_mlbm" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_mc" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_hc" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_tnrb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_bnsb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_hgb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_msrb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_brmb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_mckb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_rb" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_lves" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_canc" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_sab" class="card"></div>
  <div id="_sfh" class="card"></div>-->
 </div>
 <div class="compass">
  <img id="compass_img" src="byu_richmap_compass.png">
 </div>

<script src="byu_richmap.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check you console for errors. I don't see any element with an `id` of '_wsc'

Comment: open your developer console (`ctrl + shift + i` on most browsers), do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors showing up in the console. I added console.log("eventheard!"); to the callback function and it logs out to the console just fine. So, the event listeners are working, but something is going wrong with the CSS. What is that about clearing out the _card style?

Answer (score 0):

You're not clearing out the _card style which makes it invisible. Your code is working fine

```
var onBuildingClick = function() {
  document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.add("card");    
  document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.remove("_card");
}
```

And here too.

```
var onCompassClick = function() {
  document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.add("_card");
  document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.remove("card");
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gordon3GTMS/etvp3ko4/)

Answer (score 0):

Remember an element can have more than one class.

You click on the building, `.addClass('card')` is called, and now `#_wsc` has the class `card`.

You click on the compass, `.addClass('_card')` is called, so then `#_wsc` has the class `card _card`.

You click on the building again, and that calls `.addClass('card')`, but it already has the class `card`, so nothing happens.

Sounds like you are expecting `.addClass('_card')` to *replace* the class `card` with `_card`, but it doesn't.

How about this:

```
.card {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}

var onBuildingClick = function () {
    document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.add("visible");
}

var onCompassClick = function () {
    document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.remove("visible");
}
```

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks so much for the help! I got it. I just can't let it keep the class added in the previous event!

Answer (score 0):

As the first execution of `onCompassClick` adds `display:none` which does not get removed on consecutive clicks. Remove the class `_card` to show the 
informational card once again.

```
var onBuildingClick = function() {
  document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.remove("_card");
  document.getElementById("_wsc").classList.add("card");
}
```